# Showing a caret on firemonkey paintbox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

Does anyone know how I can add a flashing caret to a TPaintbox in Firemonkey ?

Comment: If you're able to provide a visual example (e.g. A screenshot from an existing application or a photoshopped image) of what you want to achieve, I'll look into a solution for you.

Comment: Its a text cursor like you get in any text editor to represent the current position. Look at Tmemo for example. I already have a hacked solution that uses an overlay window but I was hoping someone would know how to use TCursor and textservice to do it properly. As with most Firemonkey stuff, there is little or no documentation. I can't use Tmemo as I need various font sizes in the same document.